# What are the key parameters for passing MoPub keywords?

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, mopub

**What is the full list of *key*'s in the *key-value* pair of parameters that may be passed for each keyword type?**

MoPub's publisher [Data Passing](https://developers.mopub.com/docs/android/data-passing/) documentation mentions providing both *user data* and *contextual* keywords in order to receive relevant ads from the network. However, there is not a full description of all the key parameters that may be passed.

## User Data Keywords

From a different section of documentation [Line Item Targeting](https://developers.mopub.com/docs/ui/orders/line-item-targeting/#examples) one may see there are the following params, but no mention if this is a comprehensive list of options.

- `m_age`
- `m_gender`

## Contextual Keywords

There is no mention in the documentation of what parameters are acceptable here as key's in the *key-value* pair.

From a [twitter community](https://twittercommunity.com/t/use-spaces-in-mopub-ad-target-keywords/53574) post I can see one developer using a `discipline` parameter.